# JS is ignoring my setInterval

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I wrote a script to do some automated actions on a website (which is not mine).

That website is some kind of online shop for a pc game. The user selects an item and clicks a "withdraw" button. When the website is under heavy load (quite often), the user often gets a message saying "Heavy load - try again!" and has to click the same button again and again until he either gets the item or receives a message saying "The item was already sold!".

Everything is running inside a chrome extension!

**My script does the following:**

- Add an onClick event to the button to run a function
- Click "withdraw"
- Read the message that comes from the website
- Depends on the message:

  - "Offer is being sent..." - Do nothing and read again after interval
  - "Item was already sold!" - Stop the interval
  - "Heavy load - try again!" - Click an element to remove the message and "withdraw" again

**The problem:**

The interval is set to 2000ms, but the script just seems to be spamming the withdraw button nonstop and it seems to ignore the clearInterval().

**My code:**

```
function buy() {

    //Get the innerHTML for the box that displays the message
    var message = document.getElementsByClassName("pm-content")[0].innerHTML;

    //Message: Offer is being sent! - DO NOTHING!
    if (message == "Please wait while your trade offer is being sent...") {
        console.log("Loading: Going on!")
    }

    //Message: Item is gone! - STOP EVERYTHING!
    if (message == "Items unavailable") {
        console.log("Unavailable: Stopping!")
        clearInterval(buyInterval);
    }

    //Message: Transaction successfull! - STOP EVERYTHING
    if (message.includes("Trade offer has been sent! Code: ")) {
        console.log("Success: Stopping!")
        clearInterval(buyInterval);
    }

    if (message == "Heavy load! - Try again!") {
        console.log("Overload: Going on!")
        document.getElementById("pgwModal").click(); //Click to remove the message
        document.getElementById("withdraw").click(); //Click withdraw again

    }
}



function forceBuy() {
    buyInterval = setInterval(function(){ buy() }, 2000);
}

var button = document.getElementById("withdraw");

withdraw.onclick=function(){ forceBuy () };
```

**Any help is appreciated!**

---

## Edit_1

Code right now:

```
(function(){  //creating isolated scope to avoid using global variables.
var buyInterval; // declaring sharing variables. 

    function buy() {

    var message = document.getElementsByClassName("pm-content")[0].innerHTML;

    if (message == "Please wait while your trade offer is being sent...<br><small>(this might take up to 5 minutes)</small>") {
        console.log("Loading: Going on!")
    }

    if (message == "You cannot afford that withdrawal.") {
        console.log("Broke: Stopping!")
        document.getElementById("pgwModal").click();
        clearInterval(buyInterval);
    }

    if (message == "Items unavailable") {
        console.log("Unavailable: Stopping!")
        document.getElementById("pgwModal").click();
        clearInterval(buyInterval);
    }

    if (message.includes("Trade offer has been sent!")) {
        console.log("Success: Stopping!")
        clearInterval(buyInterval);
    }

    if (message.includes("missing")) {
        console.log("Missing: Stopping")
        document.getElementById("pgwModal").click();
        clearInterval(buyInterval);
    }

    if (message == "You can have only one pending deposit or withdrawal.") {
        console.log("Pending: Stopping!")
        document.getElementById("pgwModal").click();
        clearInterval(buyInterval);
    }

    if (message == "Too many active trades") {
        console.log("Overload: Going on!")
        document.getElementById("pgwModal").click();
        document.getElementById("withdraw").click();    
    }

    }

   function forceBuy() {
      return setInterval(function(){ buy(); }, 2000); // not necessary but                                                                                            // will be more readable
   }

  var button = document.getElementById("withdraw");

  withdraw.onclick=function(){ //making a closure to catch buyInterval variable
     buyInterval = forceBuy ();
   };

}())
```

Thanks to Vitalii for this code - It seems to work better now since it's not constantly spamming the button anymore. Sadly, the other problem persists: If the script reaches for example this part of the code:

```
    if (message.includes("Trade offer has been sent!")) {
        console.log("Success: Stopping!")
        clearInterval(buyInterval);
    }
```

It successfully reads the message and prints out "Success: Stopping!" - once every two seconds ... ongoing until i stop it from doing that by hand. It seems like clearInterval(buyInterval); is still being ignored.

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Pls show how and where you declare buyInterval

Comment: What is the corresponding HTML (of the button and maybe the surrounding form)?

Comment: buyInterval is being declared inside the forceBuy function. I am new to JS and I think I learned that there shouldn't be a "var" in front of it to make it accessable for the whole script. Is that wrong? (Will add the corresponding html to my original post in a few minutes. Not on a pc right now. - but it's just a ususal button, nothing special and the actual click on the button does work.)

Comment: Using global variables always wrong idea. Use closure instead. Ill try to rewrite your code a little bit

Comment: Thanks a lot! Could you add some comments? I don't like people to write my code - I want to understand and learn! (The website is down for maintenance right now ... can't get the html code!)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
(function(){  //creating isolated scope to avoid using global variables.
var buyInterval; // declaring sharing variables. 

    function buy() {
             ... buying action
    }

   function forceBuy() {
      return setInterval(function(){ buy(); }, 2000); // not necessary but                                                                                            // will be more readable
   }

  var button = document.getElementById("withdraw");

  withdraw.onclick=function(){ //making a closure to catch buyInterval variable
     buyInterval = forceBuy ();
   };

}())
```

Comment: So I can just add my if-code to the "function buy" to make this work? I think I only partially understand your code, but searching for isolated scopes and sharing variables might help. I will try as soon as the website gets out of maintenance mode and give feedback! Thank you, Vitalii!

Comment: Hey, the button spam stopped, but the clearInterval still doesn't seem to work. I added something to the end of my original post. I don't see why it doesn't stop the script...thank you in advance!

Comment: Seems that problem somwhere else. I recreate your example on local machine and all is ok. After btn click interval is down. Check console, and who set interval

 function forceBuy() {
console.log('interval started');
      return setInterval(function(){ buy(); }, 2000);                                                                                       
   }

Comment: Hm. Okay, thanks a lot for testing and all the help. Actually, it's not much of a problem since I the page will be refreshed after that (except if it's supposed to retry withdrawing, which works). The refresh will force stop the interval anyways. I will see this as solved. Thank you very much, vitalii!

Comment: Not a problem at all. Have a nice day :)

Comment: Oops. I just found another thing: There is a onClick on the button which starts the function with the interval. If the website gives out the message telling that it's overloaded, the button is automatically being clicked again to retry withdrawing. What happens to a running interval if it's being set over and over again? Should I remove the onClick after the interval has started? Should I stop the interval before "retrying"? Can the same interval be running parallel multiple times?

Comment: Each function invoke of setInterval produce new  interval...and! it will return NEW interval id. So, you can loose you first interval id and... you will never stop your interval. So be carefull

Comment: That explains why I cant stop it and why I get hundreds of log messages. When the website is overloaded and the script retries the withdraw by reclicking the button, the setInterval is being called. Should be able to solve this by myself, I guess. Might just kill the onClick after the interval has started and reassign it after it stopped. :)

Comment: The variable `button` is created but never used. The code works because having an element with the id "withdraw" automatically creates a global variable by that name, and that is the one used in `withdraw.onclick...` instead of `button.onclick...`

Answer (score 1):

rewrite your forceBuy function like this -

```
function forceBuy() {
    if(buyInterval) clearInterval(buyInterval);
    buyInterval = setInterval(function(){ buy() }, 2000);
}
```